# Can i add am charts dynamically on each page of dashboard. where i am having multiple page with multiple widgets?

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui, angular11, amcharts4

I have dashboard where I can add multiple pages and widget to it which follows tabset structure.
widget includes amcharts library charts
on default page amchart rendering correctly
but when I switch to another tab amchart not rendering hence data is there for chart

i am creating div with dyanmic id in html
calling chart api that returns data
applying all the properties of amcharts

Expecting

Amchart should be load for every page on tab switch

Answer (score 0):

You can put all dashboards in the carousel so that all dashboards can swipe left to right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).